# How to change app route location from child element

Tags: polymer, web-component, custom-element

I created app-route based project. Certain event I need to change the route to different root.

index.html

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

my-app.html

```
<!-- this app-route manages the top-level routes -->
<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="/:view"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{subroute}}"></app-route>

<!-- iron-pages selects the view based on the active route -->
<iron-pages selected="[[routeData.view]]" attr-for-selected="name">
  <landing-app name="home" route="{{subroute}}"></landing-app>
  <dashboard-app name="dashboard" route="{{subroute}}"></dashboard-app>
</iron-pages>
```

landing-app.html

When handler called I need to change the route to dashboard. How to do that ?

```
<dom-module id="landing-app">
  <template>
    <button on-click="_handlerCall">Change to Dashboard</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    class LandingApp extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() {return 'landing-app'}

      _handlerCall() {
        this.set('route.path', '/dashboard') // but no luck :(
      }
    }
    customElements.define(LandingApp.is, LandingApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: It should be `this.set('route.path','/dashboard');`.

Comment: It ended up with `http://localhost:8000/home/dashboard` which is I don't want. Instead I want this page to `http://localhost:8000/dashboard`

Comment: Is it possible to post entire code for that page?

Comment: I have updated question with landing-app.html. It's just simple component

Comment: Change `x-custom` to `landing-app`, `handlerClick` to `_handleCall` and put  `<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>` after `<template>`. Also, change `'route.prefix'` to `'route.path'`.

Comment: Sorry for the `x-custom` and adding <app-location... in landing-app is worked. Gosh where is the documentation for that. Anyway please make the answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add:
     `<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>` after `<template>` in landing-app.html

```
<dom-module id="landing-app">
  <template>
    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
    <button on-click="_handlerCall"> Change to Dashboard</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    class LandingApp extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() {return 'landing-app'}

      _handlerCall() {
        this.set('route.path', '/dashboard') // :)
      }
    }
    customElements.define(LandingApp.is, LandingApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Documentation for `app-location`:
https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route/elements/app-location